# Finding the conditional probabilities of a latent dirichlet allocation model

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, statistical-inference, machine-learning

Let's say I'm defining a LDA as the following:

- For each doc $m$:

  - Sample topic probabilities $\theta_m \sim Dirichlet(\alpha)$
  - For each word $n$:

    - Sample a topic $z_{mn} \sim Multinomial(\theta_m)$
    - Sample a word $w_{mn} \sim Multinomial(\beta)$

where $\alpha, \beta$ are fixed hyperparameters.

Now, to do this, I'm going to use an EM algorithm. For the 'E' step, given $\alpha$ and $\beta$, I infer $z_{mn}$ for all $n$ and $\theta_m$ for all $m$ given $w, \alpha, \beta$ using Gibbs sampling. Equivalently, I'm trying to find $p(z, \theta | w, \alpha, \beta) = \frac{p(z, \theta, w | \alpha, \beta)}{p(w|\alpha, \beta)}$ using Gibbs sampling.

At a high level, I understand what Gibbs Sampling is and what this LDA model does. We assigns topics to each word and document (assuming all others are correct). We do repeat this process in a chain until we maximize the probability of each $m$ and $n$ belonging to a particular category.

However, I'm having trouble representing the conditional probabilities of the Gibbs Sampler for this model. Where do I even start and what am I looking for when asked to find the conditional probabilities of this sampler?

Answer (score 1):

If you are finding it tricky getting started, I suggest you have a look at this paper by Griffiths and Steyvers [here](https://www.pnas.org/content/pnas/101/suppl_1/5228.full.pdf). It was well-known in the ML community for using Gibbs sampling as an alternative to variational inference for topic models. If you are looking for verbal exposition, have a look at the slides and video at around the 40:00 min mark of Lecture 14 on MCMC of this series [here](https://sailinglab.github.io/pgm-spring-2019/lectures/). The instructor briefly walks through Gibbs sampling algorithmically and in context of the paper above, and also briefly provides intuition on one of the equations there.